# How do I stop email notificatons on my Apple watch 2

Tags: email, notifications, apple-watch, yahoo

Recently I've been getting my Yahoo mail notifications on my Apple Watch 2.  I've looked everywhere I can think of on Yahoo and in my Apple settings to try to turn off.  Any ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 2):

To stop mail notifications on your Watch, go to Watch app on your iPhone.Scroll down to Mail. Then in Mail, select Custom. Here you can find alert On/Off options for each mail accounts on your iPhone.

[image: Mail Notifications]